# Making Control Button as the Hotstring's Endchars key in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make my left control as the endchars of the hotstring, but i failed to do so, any idea how to make this happen, any help is greatly appreciated
this is the line where i got error :

```
#Hotstring EndChars {LCtrl}
```

Comment: You can't do that out of the box. There are several workarounds in the AHK forum, e.g. [these two](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/6156-trigger-hotstrings-by-special-keys/).

Comment: @MCL thanks man, that's exactly the clue i'm looking for